# Google sheets - how to run a raffle? (Or how to random select from a column, excluding empty cells?)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We're doing a kind of a raffle in our company. We have some old hardware to sell. We want to create a google form, where you can select items that you are interested in purchasing. You can select anywhere from 1 to all devices available on the form.

Results are saved to a google sheet with columns:
Timestamp, Email (of a user), Terms&conditions checkbox, ITEM 1, ITEM 2, ITEM 3, ...

(yes, each item is an individual question).

At the end I have a column of X users (as many as have submited a form) and a column for each item have 0-X cells with values.

If there are more then 1 employees wishing to purchase a device, we need to choose them on random.

So there are 2 questions:

1. Is this even the best way to do it?
2. If yes, how do I randomly select a non-empty value from a column and then (probably with a vlookup or similar function) return the email of a winner?

Comment: you probably don't want it to be completely random because once someone has won something you might not want them to win for another selection over someone that hasn't won any?

Comment: Count the number of matches for a given item, then select a match via the `RANDBETWEEN()`.

Answer (score 0):

#### SUGGESTED SOLUTION

Based on the description provided, the responses to the form would look like this:

[image]

If so, [`RANDBETWEEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093507) can be used as suggested by @[Kevin P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7502029) and a formula like this can be used:

```
=INDEX(FILTER($B:$B, REGEXMATCH(D:D, "I would like to buy")), RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTIF(D:D, "I would like to buy")))
```

This provides a random email address that states `I would like to buy` on `ITEM 1`. Just drag the formula to the right, depending on the number of items the sheet currently has.

##### OUTPUT

[image]

##### REFERENCES

- [FILTER function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)

Comment: @[MattKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11075129)'s comment also makes sense, and personally, I'd like that to be fair to everyone who participated. However, I think that would fall under a different question since the OP stated that what they'd like to do is `randomly select a non-empty value` and `return the email of a winner`.